# How to call Clustered EJB application in weblogic server from a client application

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, ejb-3.0, cluster-computing, weblogic-10.x

I have  created a cluster in weblogic server with two managed servers.  My admin server is listing on 192.168.25.30:7001  and other two managed servers are listing on 192.168.25.30:7003 and 192.168.25.30:7005 .  As i want to call the EJB  application deploy on this cluster I have developed a client application. I used the 192.168.25.30:7003 address as the remote address to call from the client. When the both managed servers  up and running  my application works fine. But I want to run the application server if one manage  server is  down. When the 192.168.25.30:7005 is down  it works fine. But when 192.168.25.30:7003 is down  client requests doesn't  forward to other server.
Please  advice me is my approach correct for set up the weblogic cluster.    And  can i used one  of the managed server address to call from the client application?

Comment: The link above (in the correct answer) does not work, can someone please update the link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to do the look-up for the cluster, not only for a server. 
[Here](http://middlewaremagic.com/weblogic/?p=6193) is an example on how to do this on WebLogic.

Answer (score 1):

Problem in your approach is that you are looking up a specific managed server instance instead of the cluster/Load balancer, so you always hit the same managed instance every time.

As already answered, you need to lookup on the WL cluster.